# JS rolling link - using linkify - how to target a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, linkify

I'm using this code in my website http://jsfiddle.net/hakim/Ht6Ym/

```
var supports3DTransforms =  document.body.style['webkitPerspective'] !== undefined || 
                            document.body.style['MozPerspective'] !== undefined;

function linkify( selector ) {
  if( supports3DTransforms ) {

    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll( selector );

    for( var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        var node = nodes[i];

        if( !node.className || !node.className.match( /roll/g ) ) {
            node.className += ' roll';
            node.innerHTML = '<span data-title="'+ node.text +'">' + node.innerHTML + '</span>';
        }
    };
  }
}

linkify( 'a' );
```

I'm not very good at JS (fairly new) but at the end it targets all <'a'> tags:

```
linkify( 'a' );
```

However this is changing all links to this rollover effect. Is there anyway that I can target a specific class - lets call it .rolling - so that only the header is affected and not the other links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
linkify( 'h1 a' );
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/Ht6Ym/2131/)

if you want to select by class you can use `.`selector

```
linkify('a.myClass');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/Ht6Ym/2133/)